# pam_afs_session: what does "PAG apparently lost" message in syslog mean?

Tags: pam, openafs

We access our Debian Linux servers with ssh using GSSAPI. The servers run OpenSSH and take advantage of the pam-stack. In particular, they use `pam_afs_session`.

Every once in a while I see the following messages in the system log:

```
sshd[31799]: pam_afs_session(sshd:session): PAG apparently lost, recreating
```

What are the likely causes of this message?

Comment: The source code of the message: https://github.com/rra/pam-afs-session/blob/master/public.c
Doesn't seem to be something we have to worrie about...there is no token so it gets a new one.